# gcc, start symbol and push $0x00

Tags: gcc, assembly

So I've searched the interwebs for weeks and cannot find the answer to my questions.

I can see that the start symbol added by gcc sets up the initial two arguments (int argc, char *argv[]) and I believe the 3rd environment argument, but I have a couple questions about this. Why does it add all of this if the main() function is defined to have no arguments? Wouldn't it save space (and technically processing time) if it would just call _main without any arguments?
Second what does push $0x0 do? I have done tests and if you try to iterate through the command line arguments like what the default start symbol does then you need push $0x0 at the beginning, otherwise I have created misaligned stack errors if I do something like the following:

```
push $0x00
call _main
mov %eax, %edi
call _exit
```

also in my investigations I have found that the start symbol is added by the linker when you link to crt1.10.6.o

Any explanations or documentation would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for `_start`, as you have found, comes from an object file named `crt1.o` or similar.  That object file normally comes from source code that's part of the C library.  It is compiled in ignorance of how you have declared your `main` function, and so it has to assume you wish to make use of all three *potential* arguments.  It does no harm to set up the arguments even if `main` won't use them (other than a trivial amount of space and time, as you mention).

I deduce from `mov %eax,%edi` that this is the x86-64 ELF ABI, which means that there are no frame pointers, so the `push $0x00` is indeed just to keep the stack aligned to a 16-byte boundary, as you speculate.  (In the x86-32 ELF ABI, it would also have served as the terminator for the linked list of frame pointers.)

Comment: thank you! your deductions (not sure if thats the correct grammar) were correct.

Comment: nw my next question is why does the stack need to be aligned to a 16 byte boundary?

Comment: That allows the compiler to align variables *within* the stack frame to a 16-byte boundary, which can make things work faster.

Comment: so if you were to push 0x0 and then subtract 16 from the stack pointer it /wouldnt/ crash? I feel like im completely misunderstanding this boundary thing EDIT: so I just googled the '16 byte boundary' and now i understand the performance half of things but I still do not understand why thats related to `push $0x00` - does it force the stack to a 16 byte boundary? then how could you subtract only 8 from the stack? wouldnt you need to subtract 16 in the least?